# Is an electromagnetic field created?

Tags: electromagnetism, terminology

This question is concerned with the semantic aspects of the term.

It is common for physicists and engineers to claim that, quote, *an electromagnetic field is created.* One example might be: "an antenna connected to a radio transmitter creates an electromagnetic field when the transmitter is activated."

But if taken literally this statement implies that this field didn't exist until it was created.

My understanding is that the electromagnetic field is something that simply exists. It could be said that it is a sort of fabric that is a property of space itself. For example, consider some purely hypothetical distant, empty corner of the universe that is so far from any galaxy that no energy reaches it (and assume there is no leftover cosmic radiation there) this so-called empty space would still–theoretically speaking–contain an electromagnetic field, though the energy levels there would be in a sort of zero energy ground state.

Therefore if my understanding is correct, is it safe to assume that when physicists state that electromagnetic fields are "created", that it is a sort of a shortcut term to actually suggest that *electromagnetic energy is being introduced to a particular point in space and therefore the energy level of the field at that location is raised*? Or am I misunderstanding something fundamental?

Comment: Would you also think that before Hertz made his experiment in 1886 the same "thing" that his antenna emitted had existed before just nobody noticed it? Is this your question?

Comment: @hyportnex , No, that is not the question. The question is about the potential misuse of the term "create" when commonly used to describe a field.

Comment: In that case I admit not to know what the English verb "to create" means.

Comment: “Create” in this context means “make nonzero instead of zero”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your understanding it correct. In fact, when we say "something creates an electromagnetic field", we should probably say "something is interacting with the electromagnetic field".

To see that the electromagnetic field exists regardless of sources (another not-so-great term), we can notice that Maxwell's equations admit multiple solutions in the absence of sources. For example, electromagnetic waves are a manifestation of the electromagnetic field's degrees of freedom.

Wald's [*Advanced Classical Electromagnetism*](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691220390/advanced-classical-electromagnetism) includes some discussions concerning these issues.